# Angular+Firebase: How to best secure your database on a landing page (no authentication required)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I built a simple landing page with Angular and offer visitors who may be interested in the service to send their data through a standard sign-up form. The data are stored in a firebase database.

What would be the recommended approach to best protect my database knowing that:

- my firebase url is public (currently stored in the javascript)
- the page is public (so anyone can 'write' to the database)

So far I've added the following rules to my firebase console:

```
{
 rules: {
    ".read": "auth != null", // nobody can read 
    visitors: {
        ".write": "!data.exists()", // nobody can modify existing data
        "firstname": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 40"}, // only string with less than 40 characters
        "lastname": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 40"}, // only string with less than 40 characters
        "email": {}, // no rules
        "message": {".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 500"} // only string with less than 500 characters
    }
 }
}
```

Question 1: Are these rules good enough to protect my database or should I consider adding additional ones?

Question 2: Should I consider hiding my Firebase URL on a backend server? My idea would be to put the firebase url in a php file on the server; To update the database with new visitor data, the app would first make an ajax call to my server through the $http service, get the firebase url back, to then update the firebase database. In that case the firebase URL would not be public anymore.

What do you think? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. These rules [validate the format of the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#validating_data) that can be written. They in no way [limit who can write this data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security). Whether these validation rules are sufficient for your security requirements, only you can tell.
2. Some developers wrap the Firebase Database API with their own server. But most developers expose the database directly to the users of their app and then put their server-side logic *behind* the database, as described in [this page](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services#firebase-appengine-flexible) and diagram:

[image: Integrating App Engine Flex behind the Firebase Database]

Those developers typically end up with stricter security rules than you have now though.

Comment: Frank, Thanks for clarifying a couple of points. Regarding 1) the link provided is very helpful and I will update some of the rules accordingly.

Comment: Regarding 2), I understand from your comment that the suggestion to get the api key from the server is not an approach that would make sense. Right? Also, I am not clear from your comment if wrapping the Firebase Database API on my server/ put their server-side logic behind the database is the way to go or if validating the format of the data is good enough for a landing page.

Comment: I've told you what most developers that I interact with do. Nobody but you can decide whether something is good enough for your app.